# Catch All Email for Old Domain?

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2013, email-bounces

We've been on our new domain for over a year now and we have removed our redirects from the individual accounts but my boss wants to have a catch all email account so just in case there are messages even if they end up as spam (we're limiting the quota to 1GB).

I've checked online and found a article for a general catch all (http://www.techieshelp.com/create-a-catch-all-mailbox-in-exchange-2013/) but adjusted the rule to apply "A recipient's domain is..." olddomain.com but was getting the basic bounce back that the address does not exist.

Found on a couple other questions that I needed to take off the exception and set the old domain to an internal relay domain instead of a authoritative domain and now I'm not getting the bounce back but not getting the message in the catch all account.

Any ideas on how to get any email messages sent to our old domain redirected to a catch all account?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be authoritative for the domain, not relaying.

The bounceback message you recieved was due to recipient filtering. The message was being rejected despite your transport rule since the recipient did not exist. You would need to disable recipient filtering on the Edge Transport server to get past this.

Refer to [this Microsoft KB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) for more information.